# what is the issue with Date conversion to XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, web-services, date, dozer

I have a SOAP based webservice, in SOAP response there is a `XMLGregorianCalendar` field(defined in the response contract).

In the business layer of service, the same field is defined as `Date` type and this date is mapped as XMLGregorianCalendar value to Contract layer for SOAP Response XML generation.

The mapping from Business to Contract layer is done through `Dozer` mapper which uses a Date to XMLGregorianCalendar custom converter. The issue which I am facing currently is in some specific scenario where the date value is as follows:

`Date value being set in Business Layer is 2014-11-15 00:00:00`

And the same value is converted as

`XMLGregorianCalendar value set in contract layer is 2014-11-15T-2147483648:-2147483648:-2147483648`

I verified the same in the SOAP response, which shows above output for xml date value.

In other cases, like `2014-11-15 01:00:00`, I can see expected value in SOAP response.
when time is 00:00:00 this issue is coming. The custom converter for `Date` to `XMLGregorianCalendar` is same as specified by [dozer in this link](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/cobertura/org.dozer.converters.XMLGregorianCalendarConverter.html).

Any help why the time value is getting changed as `-2147483648:-2147483648:-2147483648`

Some forum tells its a Stackoverflow issue but couldn't link it properly with my issue scenario as in converter I am not doing any manipulation in time value.

Comment: XMLGregorianCalendar uses this [constant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED) for undefined values of hour, minute and second field.

Answer (score 0):

Following code explains why such strange time field values like -2147483648 (=Integer.MIN_VALUE) are possible (these values are symbols for undefined field values):

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xml =
    DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2014-02-05");
System.out.println(xml.toString());
System.out.println(xml.getHour());
System.out.println(xml.getMinute());
System.out.println(xml.getSecond());
```

Output:

```
2014-02-05
-2147483648
-2147483648
-2147483648
```

You have to check which class or library directly uses the field methods for printing (what is clearly a bug). I have not seen such relevant code in your link for dozer converter. So please see my answer as first hint where to look.